# Android Jetpack Compose Animation of Size Change with Duration

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

How do I add duration to content size change animation in Jetpack Compose? Trying to use **Modifier.animateContentSize()** and pass an **animationSpec** with duration, but it just snaps in or out, duration is not observed.

```
Column() {
     Modifier.animateContentSize
       (animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 5000,
       easing = LinearEasing))
     if (!isTabInvisible) {
             //some content goes here
                                
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use animateDpAsState, instead animateContentSize:

```
val animatedSize by animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = /*condition Here*/, animationSpec = tween(
        durationMillis = 5000,
        easing = LinearEasing
    )
)
```