# How to animate as size in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I want to make a size of `Column` to be 0.dp after all my animation done. I am trying to shrink my `Column` to 0.dp after all children hide. I tried below of this code

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MoveText() {
    var columnHeightPx by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val iconOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 13.dp else 0.dp,
        tween(1000)
    )
    val textOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 6.dp else 0.dp,
        tween(1000)
    )
    val viewAlpha: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
        )
    )
    ScrollComposeTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        columnHeightPx = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                    }
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = iconOffsetAnimation),
                    alpha = viewAlpha,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = textOffsetAnimation),
                    text = "Hello, Anna",
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = viewAlpha),
                )
            }
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 10.dp),
                onClick = {
                    visible = !visible
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Move Text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this when animation completed :(

[image]

I am trying to shrink my size like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tyb8MHJMW44). In this video, I only want to shrink the `Icon` & `Text` with `Column`, but I am getting the above image problem. I tried to search in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080719/8266651) and I found to use `animateSizeAsState`, but I am not sure it'll work or not because it gives error

```
val heightInDp = animateSizeAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) columnHeightPx else 0,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
        )
    )
```

Error on `targetValue`

```
Type mismatch.
 Required:  Size
 Found: { Comparable  & Number }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`animateSizeAsState` returns as `State<Size>` object,

`Size` contains width and height parameters in pixel in Float unit but what you need is height is in dp. You can convert pixel to dp or dp to pixel using `Density`.

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val heightInDp = animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = if (visible) with(density){columnHeightPx.toDp()} else 0.dp,
    animationSpec = tween(
        durationMillis = 1000,
    )
)
```